# Compare values in two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. In my application I log status of file for each job at each stage.(e.g. Start,pre processing,processing,finished etc) .
2. I want that , at the end of every day one Stored procedure will run and it will check if certain job was expected to give certain status for certain number of times.
3. If it is expected then it sets message as 'Successful'. If not, then it gives error accordingly.(e.g. Pre processing status is missing then set message as 'Pre processing failed' etc.).
4. My approach is to  create one look up table which will contain the ideal scenarios for
   each job, each status, and their count for the day.

   - then I will take count of all statuses for specific job from my Log table and
   - compare it with look up table one by one. I am not sure if I am opting right way to implement this.

   Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Log Table:

```
    Create Table Log_for_Jobs
    (
      Date_time datetime not null, 
      Job_name varchar(20) not null,
      Job_status varchar(10) null,
      Log_message varchar(100) null
    )
```

and then create a SP to check the jobs,put the result into this table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two tables like you suggest, one to log the history of your jobs and the other to store possible states.

**JobState**

```
ID | Description
 1 | Start
 2 | Pre processing
 3 | Processing
 4 | Finished
 5 | Error
```

I think you have two outcomes here, either your application records an error at a given state (E.g. during 3 - Processing) or it stops and doesn't record anything further.  I've added 5 - Error to represent the application error state.

The next thing to consider is do you need to record each state or can you overwrite the previous state?  Two possible reasons for recording each state are to know the time taken on each step and to record extra info along with each step (e.g. Processing 150 rows, etc).  But if it's not needed you could just update the row for that job with the next state and for success it should end in 4 - Finished.

**JobHistory**

```
ID | JobID | JobTime           | JobStateID | Message
 1 |    55 | 1 Jan 2015 9:45am |          1 | Start file c:\test.txt
 2 |    55 | 1 Jan 2015 9:47am |          2 | Preprocessing 117 rows...
 3 |    55 | 1 Jan 2015 9:55am |          3 | Processing
 4 |    55 | 1 Jan 2015 9:57am |          5 | ERROR: Unexpected character at line 321 - '@'
```

I'm assuming it has to complete a previous step to get to the next one.  If that is the case then you just need to select all jobs where state = 4 to get all that completed successfully (then do something with them).

```
SELECT *
FROM JobHistory
WHERE State = 4
// AND JobTime is within the last day?
```

And select all jobs, group by job id having max(state) <> 4 for those with errors.  You can then do something with the max state, it's either 5 - Error (use error message logged in table) or 1, 2, 3, so report that processing stopped at this step.

```
SELECT JobID, Max(JobStateId) as EndJobStateId, Min(JobTime) as StartTime, Max(JobTime) as EndTime
FROM JobHistory
GROUP BY JobID
HAVING Max(JobStateId) <> 4
```